# Character Spacing in JTextComponent

Tags: java, swing, pdf, fonts

I am trying to make my Swing GUI match the PDF report that my application is printing. This requires limiting the length of text inputs.

Having nearly found it by measuring the width of strings using `FontMetrics.stringWidth()`, I have discovered that by default Swing has very little (if any) character spacing. 
This is particularly clear in a string of capital Ws.

How can I adjust character spacing for a Swing JTextComponent, whether a JTextField or a JTextArea, or anything else?

Comment: Have you considered using something like iText or Jasper Reports to render the PDF?  Or are you looking for the ability to do WYSIWYG editing?

Comment: Yes to all. :-) I am using iText to fill a PDF template and I need the ability to do WYSIWYG editing sick that data entered is limited to fit in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with custom GlyphPainter based on GlyphVector. It provides method

```
 setGlyphPosition(int glyphIndex, Point2D newPos)
```

you can use to change space between characters

See more [here](http://java-sl.com/gp_effects.html). You can download [the example with source code](http://java-sl.com/download/gp_effects.jar) and play with the code